# Laravel function in User model that will be called for User::all()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Imagine I have this function in User model:

```
public function loadOrderStatus(){
    $this->load(['status' => function ($query) {
        $query->ofTranslatedStatuses();
    }]);
}
```

This function works fine for single model instance like : `User::first()`
but how this function can be used with `User::all()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scopeQuery in the User model

```
public function scopeStatusAll($query)
{
    return $query->with(['status' => function ($query) {
        $query->ofTranslatedStatuses();
    }]);
}
```

call it with

```
User::statusAll()->get();
```

Or you could put a static function in User model

```
public static function statusAll()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return $users->load(['status' => function ($query) {
        $query->ofTranslatedStatuses();
    }]);
}
```

call it with

```
User::statusAll();
```